# create a circle image with text

Tags: html, css

I want to create  a circle image with text like a picture, i upload in below

[image]

But i create a circle image with text like this show in after correct image

[image]

```css
.circles {
  margin: auto;
  height: 73px;
  width: 130px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -169px;
}

.tit {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div className="circle">
  <img src={imageupload} className="cirimage" />

</div>
<div className="circles">
  <p className="tit">Title</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.round {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  background-color: #e6baba;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -38px;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
   

 <div class="round">
  <div class="text">
    Text
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    Add Image Here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your CSS file

```
.text-container {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.image-container {
  background-color: #e6baba;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 9;
  position: relative;
  top: -38px;
  
}
.circle-container {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Use HTML as below

```
 <div class="circle-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    Add Image Here
  </div>
 <div class="text-container">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```